# "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc' what(): std::bad_alloc" But it is strange, I have a lot of available memory

Tags: c++, pointers, runtime-error, delete-operator

I wrote a class, and than I used this to create another one and used both in a test program. My second class uses dynamic allocation so I followed the recommendations and create The Big Three, a creator, a copy creator and a destructor. But when I try to use a class friend operator the program stops and return the message above. Let me show some code:

```
class matrix
{
public:
    int n;
    complex **M;
    matrix(int dim); //construtor
    matrix(int dim, double a);//construtor
    matrix(const matrix &obj);//construtor de copia (necessario para passar objetos para funções)
    ~matrix(); //destrutor
    friend matrix operator *(matrix a, matrix b);
};

matrix::matrix(int dim) 
{
    int i = 0;
    n = dim;
    M = new complex*[dim];
    cout << "criando objeto \n";

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        M[i] = new complex [dim];
    }
}

matrix::matrix(int dim, double a) 
{
    int i = 0, j = 0; 
    n = dim;
    M = new complex*[dim];
    cout << "criando objeto \n";

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        M[i] = new complex [dim];
    }

    for(i=0;i <dim; i++){
        for(j=0; j<dim; j++){
            M[i][j] = complex(a,0);     
        }
    }
}

matrix::matrix(const matrix &obj)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    M = new complex*[n];
    cout << "criando copia de objeto \n";

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        M[i] = new complex [n];
    }

    for(i=0;i <n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<n; j++){
            M[i][j] = obj.M[i][j];      
        }
    }
    n = obj.n;
}

matrix::~matrix()
{
    int i;
    cout << "destruindo obejto \n";
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        delete [] M[i];
    delete M;
}

matrix operator *(matrix a, matrix b)
{
    int i,j,k;
    matrix mult(a.n, 0);
    bool dim;
    if(a.n == b.n) dim = true;
    else dim = false;
    if(dim == true) 
    {   
        for(i=0; i < a.n; i++){ 
            for(j=0; j < a.n; j++){
                for(k=0; k < a.n; k++){ 
                    mult.M[i][j] = mult.M[i][j] + a.M[i][k]*b.M[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return mult;
    }
    else return zeros(a.n);
}
```

Well, I really don't know why I'm getting this error message, I would be grateful if anyone could help me to solve this out.

Comment: Your copy constructor has undefined behaviour: `M = new complex*[n];`, but you assign `n` much later.

Comment: By the way, this is a bad way to implement an `n*n` matrix. You are making multiple allocations in your ctors. If a later allocation throws, the earlier allocations are leaked.

Comment: Further, `operator *` should take its arguments by const ref, not by value, and should really be implemented in terms of `operator *=`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really fixed the main problem, but I'm still getting a segmantation fault error now. Any idea?

Comment: "operator * should take its arguments by const ref, not by value" why is that? "and should really be implemented in terms of operator *=" to avoid misunderstood with pointer unary operator *?

Comment: Taking arguments by const ref avoids unnecessarily copying the operands. The idea is that `operator *=` can't be implemented efficiently in terms of `operator*`, but `operator*` can be efficiently implemented in terms of `operator*=`, so you should put the multiplication logic in `operator*=` and have `operator*` just use that. (`operator*=` can store the result in place and make no new `matrix`, while `operator*` must return the result by value so must make at least one new `matrix` to store the results in, so implementing `operator*=` using `operator*` incurs at least one unnecessary copy.)